# Add numbers from 100 to 1000 that are divisible by five AND six

Tags: java

My program is correct except for that in the end, the program must output two `\n\n`. Just like that. Only on the last line, however. At every ten sets, it should only output one `\n`. THis is what the program should look like:

```
1   2   0       1   5   0       1   8   0       2   1   0
2   4   0       2   7   0       3   0   0       3   3   0
3   6   0       3   9   0  \n   4   2   0       4   5   0
4   8   0       5   1   0       5   4   0       5   7   0
6   0   0       6   3   0       6   6   0       6   9   0  \n
7   2   0       7   5   0       7   8   0       8   1   0
8   4   0       8   7   0       9   0   0       9   3   0
9   6   0       9   9   0  \n  \n
```

This is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise4_10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          int count = 1;
          for (int i = 100; i <= 1000; i++) {
              if (i%5==0 && i%6==0)
              System.out.print((count++ % 10 != 0) ? i + " ": i + "\n" );
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this before the closing brace for main:

```
System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: You can even do `System.out.println()`

Comment: whats before closing brace for main? Sorry, I'm completely new to this

Comment: Could you tell me the reasoning behind it? Prior to posting my question, I was trying to do exactly what you suggested I do, but I was putting it right after  System.out.print((count++ % 10 != 0) ? i + " ": i + "\n" );. It worked when I put it after the closing bracket: 
                System.out.print((count++ % 10 != 0) ? i + " ": i + "\n" );

        }
        System.out.println("");

Comment: You already have the single newline stuff correct and just need one more newline at the end.  just println before exiting your main method.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise4_10 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 100; i <= 1000; i++) {

            // You can avoid 5 & 6 by using 30 ( 5*6) - optional
            if (i%30==0)

                //You can skip using another variable count & use i for the same - optional
                System.out.print(((i+1) % 10 != 0) ? i + " ": i + "\n" );

        }

        //Will print \n only in the end
        System.out.print("\n" );
    }

}
```